# Google cloud storage using stream instead of bytebuffer - java

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the following code:

```
    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
    GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, fileName);
    GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
        .mimeType(contentType)
        .acl("public-read")
        .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value")
        .build();
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
        gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);
    outputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray));
    outputChannel.close();
```

The problem is that when I try to store video files, I have to store the file in the byteArray which could cause memory issues.

But I cannot find any interface to do the same with stream.

questions:

1. Should I worry about mem issues in the appengine srv, or are they capable of keeping a 1 min video in mem?
2. is it possible to use stream instead of byte array? how?
3. I'm reading the bytes as `byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);` should I use the byte array as a real buffer  and just read chunks and upload them to the GCS? how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory available depends on the appengine instance type you've configured. Streaming this data seems like a good idea if you can.

Not sure about the GcsService api, but looks like you can do this using the gcloud Storage api:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/blob/master/gcloud-java-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.java

This code might work (untested)...

```
final BlobInfo info = BlobInfo.builder(bucket.getBucketName(), "name").contentType("image/png").build();

final ReadableByteChannel src = Channels.newChannel(stream);
final WriteChannel dst = gcsStorage.writer(info);

fastChannelCopy(src, dst);

private void fastChannelCopy(final ReadableByteChannel src, final WritableByteChannel dest) throws IOException {
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * 1024);
    while (src.read(buffer) != -1) {
        buffer.flip();      // prepare the buffer to be drained
        dest.write(buffer); // write to the channel, may block
        // If partial transfer, shift remainder down
        // If buffer is empty, same as doing clear()
        buffer.compact();
    }
    // EOF will leave buffer in fill state
    buffer.flip();

    // make sure the buffer is fully drained.
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        dest.write(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the blob API is not supported any more - I don't think this code will work.

Comment: This is not the blob api. Just because you see a class named BlobInfo does not mean this is the unsupported blob api. I'm currently using this api in a production system that gets significant traffic. Please look here and reconsider your downvote: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.0/index.html

Comment: Top link unfortunately broken.